# Explaining Probabilities in Python with Naive Bayes

Tags: python, naive-bayes-algorithim

I have run some data on the possibility of churn in a telecom company based on 6 variables

[image: []

How now do I interpret the output below for the probabilities:
[image]

Comment: Please [avoid screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7311767), you can just copy/paste the text.

Answer (score 0):

First to be clear, here the log of the probabilities is printed and this is not convenient to interpret anything. You can manually calculate the real probability value by taking the exponential. For example: $exp(-0.1585)=0.853$ and $exp(-1.92)=0.146$. So the prior probabilities are $P(Y=0)=0.85$ and $P(Y=1)=0.15$, and you can check this, for instance $1991/(1991+342)=0.85$.

The features parameters give the conditional prob of feature $X_i$ given class $Y$, for example the first is $P(Int.I.Plan=1|Y=0)=exp(-8.717)=0.000164$. This means that among the instances which have class 0, 0.0164% have the feature `Int.I.Plan` active. The probs sum to 1 for one line, i.e. given one class.

Comment: Thanks @Erwan for this but I am confused with the interpretation of the conditional probability above.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I am having an issue with understanding the concept. In the model "0" is No to Churn and "1" is Yes to Churn . So P(Eve Mins=1|Y=0)=exp(-0.7312+=48.13% is saying that "Given that No Churn has happened that there will be a 48.13% that customer will churn for those using the evening plan". Is  my reasoning correct? So the corresponding line for Eve Min of  exp(-0.777)=45.97% should be "Given that Churn has occurred there is a 45.97% that customers on even min will not churn? Thanks